# xampp mac os x "this application requires admin privileges"

Tags: macos, xampp, privileges

When I try to start `xampp` (manager-osx) on Mac OS X Yosemeti 10.10,

I get this error :

> this application requires admin privileges

It doesn't ask any password like it used to.

Comment: This question is off-topic. It isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 37):

I find the solution:
for some reason, owner has been changed. I changed it back to root, and now it works again :

```
$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
$ sudo chown -R root manager-osx.app
```

Then input your system password when requested and press enter.

Comment: For others who are wondering why this solution did not work for them , Make sure you are navigating to xamppfiles folder not stopping on XAMPP

Comment: This happened to me as well... had to do sudo on the chown command... the bigger question is... why did this ownership change occur?

Answer (score 8):

It works with this

$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles

$ sudo chown -R root manager-osx.app

Answer (score -1):

Neither of the suggestions by @sonique or @ishaalans worked in my case:

1. Right click to open application package contents (logged in as an admin)
2. Find the executable file of the app in question
3. Type sudo into Terminal
4. Drag and drop the executable on the Terminal cursor after sudo and it will populate the file path
5. Click enter and enter admin password
6. Voila! It opened immediately for me and should for you if all else fails